# Allow overlapping elements and avoid displacement

Tags: html, css

I'm kinda stuck with this if someone could shed some light I'd be very grateful.

Ok here I go.

I did this kind of custom table using a div for the table body, a nested one for the content
and each cell is an span element.Everything is fine but one thing.

What I try to achieve is when user hovers over a cell (span), if the content is too long (which a lot actually are) to fit in the width,it pop ups itself and show the content in some kind of tooltip.

Actually already achieve the purpouse,well kind of, but the cell(span) displaces the content of the row if the content is larger, and that's the point of asking,How can avoid that behaviour? How can I allow the content overlap the rest of the row and avoid displacement?

For a better explanation check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fuyn14en/2/

Here's the code (same as in the fiddle).

Html:

```
<div id="tabla">
     <div id="tablaContenido">
          <div class="tablaFila">
               <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</span>                    
               <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrge Content makes the row displace how can i overlap so all other cells keep where they suppose to be?</span>
               <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</span>
               <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</span>
               <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</span>
               <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</span>  
               <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</span>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#tabla{
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       display: table;
       padding-bottom: 20px;
       position: relative;
       display: inline;
}

.tablaFila{
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    float: left;
    display: table-row;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

.tablaFilaContenido{
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;  
    padding: 5px 5px;
    width: 11%; 
    white-space: nowrap;    
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.tablaFilaContenido:hover{ 
     background-color: #B2FF66;
     content: attr(title);
     z-index: 1;  
     display: block;
     width: auto;                
     position: static;
}
```

Please ask if something is missing or not clear :)

Any idea or suggestion ?

Comment: Check out barelyfitz. http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ it has very good examples of css positioning.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,

HTML

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="7.css" />
</head>
<body> 
      <div class="tablaFila">
           <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</p></span>                    
           <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrge Content makes the row displace how can i overlap so all other cells keep where they suppose to be?</p></span>
           <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</p></span>
           <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</p></span>
           <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</p></span>
           <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</p></span>  
           <span class="tablaFilaContenido">Short Content</p></span>
      </div>


 <body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#tabla{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: table;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   position: absolute;
   display: inline;
```

}

.tablaFila{

```
width: 100%;
height: 15px;
float: left;
display: table-row;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
padding: 0;
```

}

.tablaFilaContenido{

```
margin: 0;
border: 0;  
padding: 5px 5px;
width: 11%; 
white-space: nowrap;    
float: left;
display: table-cell;
font-size: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
```

}

.tablaFilaContenido:hover{

```
 background-color: #B2FF66;
 content: attr(title);
 z-index: 1;  
 display: inline;
 width: auto;                
 position: absolute;
```

}

Comment: That´s something.Is it possible to put it over itself i mean the cell? I thougt it was possible with a z-index but it seems not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/fuyn14en/7/

The edits I've made are:

- Removed content: attr(title); from cell hover (I'll explain this below)
- Added display: inline; to cell hover.
- Changed position: static; to position: absolute; on cell hover. This is the main property that prevents other elements being pushed forward. When this is positioned absolutely, all other elements basically don't recognize that it exists.
- Added a selector for .tablaFilaContenido:hover + .tablaFilaContenido. This is the adjacent selector. When we hover over a cell, we are giving it absolute positioning, and all elements after it are being pulled backwards. By using this selector we can push them back to where they are supposed to be. I made it so when you hover over a cell, the next cell is given margin-left: 11% (the width of the previous cell), and padding-left: 15px (the padding of the previous cell + the left padding of *this* cell.

I had to remove "content: attr(title);" because when you remove the mouse away from a specific table cell (after hovering over it), the margin and padding applied with .tableFilaContenido:hover+.tablaFilaContenido would be retained, leaving cells out of place.

```
    .tablaFilaContenido:hover {
        background-color: #B2FF66;
         z-index: 1;  
         display: inline;
         width: auto;
         position: absolute;
    }

    .tablaFilaContenido:hover + .tablaFilaContenido { 
        margin-left: 11%; 
        padding-left: 15px; 
    }
```

Comment: I thought I was not very clear at asking (thought yours is a good aproach same as @Nish example), could it be possible to put the tooltip over itself instead of the end of the row ?